# How to update session userdata value when we make a change in database?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to update one of the value in userdata session. I set the userdata like this:

```
$data_e = array (
    'id' => $get[0]->id,
    'name' => $get[0]->name,
    'id_company' => $get[0]->id_company
);

$this->session->set_userdata('user_data', $data_e);
```

I've tried to do this:

```
$data['name'] = $this->clean_input->clean($this->input->post('name', TRUE));

$this->session->set_userdata('name', $data['name']);
```

But it doesn't work. Thanks for the help

Comment: `$_SESSION['user_data']['name'] = $this->clean_input->clean($this->input->post('name', TRUE));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help you :

check for session, destroy it and then re-initialize it

```
if ($this->session->has_userdata('name'))
{
   $this->session->unset_userdata('name');
   $data['name'] = $this->clean_input->clean($this->input->post('name', TRUE));
   $this->session->set_userdata('name', $data['name']);
}
```

for more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html